# Android avoid OnResume

Tags: java, android

I have 3 Acivity based application, It's work flow like this `MainActivity` `ListView` and `DetailView`. when onResume event trigger , need to call MainActivity. without going to other two activity.

Is there any way to call `MainActivity` when onResume event trigger?

Thank You

Comment: You haven't really described your problem. *Why* do you need to call MainActivity from onResume? onResume from *which* Activity? You shouldn't be calling any methods across the boundaries of an Activity.

Comment: Let assume user pause the application in ListView  or DetailView. When resume the application it's goes to one of them. But without going to those two view, I need to navigate user in to  MainActivity.

Comment: Do you mean that after exiting the app from whichever of these 3 activities, when going back to your app, the MainActivity should appear intead of other activities?

Comment: Yes, Exactly that what i need to do.

Comment: call finish() in the onPause() or onStop() in the ListView and DetailView activies, so that the activites will get killed and UI returns to MainActivity

Comment: Can you navigate between ListView and DetailsView activies or does everything flow through the MainActivity?

Comment: Please see my update, I just tested and this should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the `android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"` attribute for you MainActivity in the AndroidManifest.xml file. See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#clear) to find why and more details. I think this is the most convenient way to meet your demand.

**Edit:**
I just tested and found this only works when you exit the app and launch the app from the app drawer(**NOT long press on HOME and select the app**).

If you want to always bring the root activity to the front, no matter when you re-launch the app or from the recent screen. You can declare `"android:launchMode="singleTask"` for the root activity, here, the MainActivity.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I can think of is to start the activity again in the onResume of all your other activities:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

The user will still be able to hit the back button and go back to the previous activity, however.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to quit your List/Details views when the user closes your app, have them `finish()` themselves in their `onPause` which is called when your `Activity` is closed.

The only caveat here is that calling `finish()` will move it one Activity back in the ActivityStack so if your MainActivity isn't the one launching the List/Details views, it will not go back to the MainActivity.  In this case, you could specify in the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name="sample.activity.MyActivity" android:noHistory="true" />
```

to prevent the List/Details activities from ever being put into the history.